# java start a thread using isAlive()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm new to multithreaded; is this the right way to go about starting a thread?

```
if(!sesThread.isAlive()) {
    try {
        sesThread.start();
    }catch(IllegalThreadStateException e) { System.out.println("y u start");}
}
```

**premise**: caller processes bytearrays and push it to a queue. session thread is to deque and further process them until queue is empty and hence sessions's run() returns

**problem**: im getting alot of exceptions getting thrown and even so my session thread for some reason has its run() being called twice!

i.e. (start > start > end > end) NOT (start > end > start > end)

Is there some way to synchronize or ensure this "lazy instantiation"-ish mechanism call start only once?

ps. im making a multithreaded UDP socket server aimed at delivery speed, so itd be great to have minimal delay and not some thread.sleep() prior to isAlive()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not use this mechanism.

Your consumer thread should not terminate just because the queue is empty. Threads are expensive to start. You should use a `BlockingQueue` and have your consumer thread block when the queue is empty.

```
public class TwoThreads {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TwoThreads:Test");
        new TwoThreads().test();
    }

    // The end of the list.
    private static final Integer End = -1;

    static class Producer implements Runnable {

        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    queue.add(i);
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
                // Finish the queue.
                queue.add(End);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Just exit.
            }
        }

    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable {

        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

        public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean ended = false;
            while (!ended) {
                Integer i = queue.take();
                ended = i == End;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

    }

    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        Thread pt = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
        Thread ct = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
        // Start it all going.
        pt.start();
        ct.start();
        // Wait for it to finish.
        pt.join();
        ct.join();
    }

}
```

Comment: wow thanks man, just checked out the javadocs, was curious about how do I go about doing the waiting code but turns out take() handles it for you. But is there an alternative to return from take() without sending out a 'end of queue' element as I cant use byte[0] as the producer will send out bytearrays of such value.

Comment: @iluvAS - If you use a static final object as your `poison pill` you can check for it using `==`. Your compiler will probably warn you but this is one of the rare cases where comparing objects using `==` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A Thread which is not started is just another object. Calling `isAlive()` makes no sense. A *running* thread can be alive, a thread object can't.

> Is there some way to synchronize or ensure this "lazy
>   instantiation"-ish mechanism call start only once?

A thread can be *started only once*. Calling `start()` again will lead to `IllegalThreadStateException`